# Codeigniter: The requested URL was not found in the server

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, unicode, fonts

I am not good in English so consider my grammatical mistake.

I am from Bangladesh so my client wants Bangla URL for SEO friendly. I tried to passing some particulars Unicode word in URL.

Normally everything is ok but when I pass this 'অর্থনীতি' types of word browser show object not found. I used url_encode/url_decode, permitted_uri_chars, and more other suggestion too but this browser message is same. can I pass this types of word in the URL?

I attached two picture. one is URL working fine and another is not working well.

[image]

**** Solution ****

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteBase /example3/ 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
   RewriteRule . /example3/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: show the code of controller function ```news_details()```

Comment: public function news_details($news_id) {
        
        $data = array();
        $data['news'] = $this->WelcomeModel->full_news($news_id);
        $this->load->view('full-news', $data);
    }

Answer (score 0):

first of all make sure you enable query string in **config.php** file

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: I do but the result is same. and i also change system>core>URL.php uf8_enabled

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to change your controller function.

```
public function news_details($news_id, $news_slug)
{
$data = array();
$data['news'] = $this->WelcomeModel->full_news($news_id);
$this->load->view('full-news', $data);
}
```

You just need to add this parameter `$news_slug` in your controller function

***Edit 1 :***

This is my function I tried :

```
function news_details($id, $slug){
    print_r("News Id    : ". $id);
    print_r("<br>");
    print_r("News Slug  : ".$slug);
}
```

And this is what my output is :

[image]

***Edit 2 :***
Second screenshot as per your provided string
[image]

Comment: kishor10d, brother i used $news_sulg. Here no parameter problem. Codeigniter URL does not allow this types of characters

Comment: @KhyrulAlam : I will do something and get back to you.

Comment: @KhyrulAlam : I edited my answer. I setup a demo of codeigniter and attached the screenshot fot the same. This is what you want right? or some thing else, just let me know. My codeigniter version is 3.1.1

Comment: Can you please used this text to your code "অর্থনীতি". pass this text to your slug parameter. i waiting to your result.

Comment: @KhyrulAlam : I pass your provided string as slug, and result screenshot attached to the answer.

Comment: @KhyrulAlam I got the error brother, add ```index.php``` in your url, it will work. We will find some solution on this.

Comment: yes, when i used index.php it's work fine. it's mean the problem is .htaccess. My Rewrite engine was not permitted this types of word

Comment: @KhyrulAlam: yes, correct! I am trying it will ```.htaccess``` now.

Comment: brother, i got a solution. this code work nicely for me

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /example3/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /example3/index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: @KhyrulAlam : Great, post it as answer to your question itself. It will helpful to others. And please check it on live server too.